# Saving data into a table

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-insert, insert-update

I try to save the data into a table but it doesn't work. But another program with similar code does, why?

```
<?php
    $nik =  $_POST['nik'];
    $no_kk =  $_POST['no_kk'];
    $nama =  $_POST['nama'];
    $lahir =  $_POST['lahir'];          
    $jenis_kelamin =  $_POST['jk'];
    $nope =  $_POST['no_hp']; 
    $no_tps =  $_POST['no_tps'];
    $pekerjaan =  $_POST['pekerjaan']; 
    $pendidikan =  $_POST['pendidikan'];
    $agama = $_POST['agama'];
    $tgl = $_POST['tgl'];      

    $simpan=$_POST['simpan'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_tj_beringin (NIK, NO_KK, NAMA_LENGKAP, JENIS_KELAMIN, TEMPAT_LAHIR, TANGGAL_LAHIR, AGAMA, PENDIDIKAN_AKHIR, JENIS_PEKERJAAN, NO_HP, NO_TPS) VALUES ('$nik', '$no_kk', '$nama','$alamat','$jenis_kelamin','$lahir','$tgl', '$agama', '$pendidikan', '$pekerjaan', '$nope', '$no_tps')";
    $data = mysqli_query('$koneksi, $sql');
    if(isset($simpan)){
         $data = $koneksi->query($sql);
         if($data){
             ?>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                alert ("Data Berhasil Disimpan");
                window.location.href="?page=anggota";
             </script>

             <?php
         }
         else{
              echo "error";
         }
    }
?>
```

Comment: "It doesn't work". What happens? What's the error message? Or the data, if it's returning the wrong data? see [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: And I second that you should be using prepared statements. I highly recommend `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong: `...VALUES ('$nik', '$no_kk', '$nama'...)`.

The problem that in PHP, single quotes *prevent variable expansion*. So you're never actually inserting the value of `$nik` (or anything else).

A second problem is that you should never, *EVER* insert data from the web request directly into your database.  *NEVER TRUST USER DATA*.  That's a *HUGE* vulnerability.

A neat solution to *BOTH* problems is simply to use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

Comment: It looks like the `INSERT` statement is contained within double quotes, so the variables should be expanding. Absolutely agree about prepared statements. They make for cleaner code, too.